# A Common Lisp program error

Tags: random, lisp, common-lisp

This is the code:

```
 (defun my-random (max &optional least)
    (setf max (+ max 1))
    (if (null least)
        (random max)
        (if (numberp least)
            (if (numberp max)
                (let ((x (random (- max least))))
                    (+ x least))
                (format t "~%在my-random函数中发现错误: 第一个输入值不是一个数字!~%"))
            (format t "~%在my-random函数中发现错误: 第二个输入值不是一个数字!~%"))))
```

;my-random 100 1

```
(defun prozentual (probability command)
    (if (numberp probability)
        (if (listp command)
            (if (> 101 probability)
                (if (> probability (my-random 101 1))
                    command)
                (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 概率不得多于100!~%))
            (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 第二个参数不是一个命令!~%))
        (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 第一个参数不是一个数字!~%)))
```

;prozentual 100 (format t "as")

```
This is the Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.6 runs on the results:
? (load "mika.cl")
> Error: Reader error: Illegal symbol syntax.
> While executing: CCL::%PARSE-TOKEN, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 > (my-random 101 1)
61
1 > (my-random 101 100)
100
1 > (my-random 101 100)
100
1 > (my-random 101 100)
100
1 > (my-random 101 100)
100
```

Now "prozentual" function can not be used ..

Comment: What is your question about the code?

Comment: Why the procedure to be wrong?

Comment: Sorry..I do not know the error information is described to me what

Comment: You're missing the ending doublequotes `"` on the `format` lines in `prozentual`.

Answer (score 9):

YOu're missing the doublequotes at the end of the `format` strings.

```
(defun prozentual (probability command)
    (if (numberp probability)
        (if (listp command)
            (if (> 101 probability)
                (if (> probability (my-random 101 1))
                    command)
                (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 概率不得多于100!~%"))
            (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 第二个参数不是一个命令!~%"))
        (format t "~%在prozentual函数中发现错误: 第一个参数不是一个数字!~%")))
```

Comment: @46897asd I would recommend an editor with a decent lisp mode as the syntax highlighting in your editor should make it very clear when a double-quote like that is missing.